# error in java regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to verify the existence of some text like this in java :

```
finally{
    if (session != null && session.isOpen()){
        session.clear();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

now I wrote the following regex to verify it in java :

```
finallyAsString.matches("(.*)if(.*)\Q!=\E(.*)null(.*)\Q&&\E(.*)\Q.isOpen()\E(.*)\Q.clear()\E(.*)\Q.close()\E(.*)");
```

but my the compiler tells me that I'm using "illigal escape character". can anybody help? thanks.

Comment: this is not the same as the question you mentioned @pshemo

Comment: It certainly looks like the answer to that question would fix your problem. If it doesn't you should explain exactly why it doesn't work, so that people can better answer the question.

Comment: You just created same error in different way. Solution is the same for bot questions -> escape ``\`` since in string it is metacharacter used for escaping metacharacters, or creating other characters like tab `\t`.

Comment: @MaxZoom they are tools for escaping characters, anything between them will be treated as is.

Comment: @AshkanKzme For your edit, I think you should post another question, as the issue is completely different. Also, take a look at the java documentation for regexes, not all languages share the same notation, what you can use in javascript (or another language) might not be valid in java.

Comment: @BackSlash I know what you are saying, but I dont think that's the case here.

Comment: @AshkanKzme it works fine for me. Check [here](http://ideone.com/pix8bX0)

Comment: @MaxZoom you forgot to give me the code, the page is a blank ide.

Comment: @MaxZoom its just an standard ide page, empty!

Comment: Since I can not add new post, I have edit BackSlash answer. I hope it is acceptable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32273119/2 that is not proper edit. If one answer solved your current problem, but new problem appeared then you should ask new question, not change old question into new one, because it makes all previously posted answers invalid. I rolled back your question to its original form. Remember that edits are meant to clean your question and provide more context about *current problem* you ware asking, not to ask update your post into new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslash in a string is used to escape. So *just* the backslash means you have an incomplete escape character, you need to complete it by adding another backslash:

```
(.*)if(.*)\\Q!=\\E(.*)null(.*)\\Q&&\\E(.*)\\Q.isOpen()\\E(.*)\\Q.clear()\\E(.*)\\Q.close()\\E(.*)
```

**The whole code:**

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
      String finallyAsString = "finally{ if (session != null && session.isOpen()){session.clear();session.close();}}";
      boolean match = finallyAsString.matches("(.*)if(.*)\\Q!=\\E(.*)null(.*)\\Q&&\\E(.*)\\Q.isOpen()\\E(.*)\\Q.clear()\\E(.*)\\Q.close()\\E(.*)");
      System.out.println(match);
    }
}
```

Comment: so the problem is that I have "\n" in my text. that it cannot detect!

Comment: please edit the answer so I accept it.